# Is it possible to access a related list of data using force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is it possible to display a list of related records using `<force:recordData` as the data source?

Example:

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="targetRecord" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="fields" type="String[]" default="Name, Invoice_Lines__r" />

<force:recordData 
    recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
    fields="{!v.fieldsToQuery}"
    mode="VIEW" 
    targetRecord="{!v.record}" 
    targetFields="{!v.targetRecord}"
    targetError="{!v.recordError}" />

<lightning:formattedText title="ID" value="{!v.record.Name}" />

<ul>
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.record.Invoice_Lines__r}" var="line">
     <li>line.Name</li>
   </aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

The above example gives me this error:

> No such column 'Invoice_Lines__r' exists on entity 'Appointment__c'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I heard of it being on the roadmap at an unspecified stage but not yet.

Comment: Is there any kind of `Standard List Controller` feature available in Lightning?

Comment: Nope. You'll need to use Apex to query.

Comment: @Robs This was the question i asked in the last lightning tour to the Director  of lightning Platform [kamyar](https://www.linkedin.com/in/kamyar-seradjfar-5ab0911/) **Safe harbour** that's something they are considering Standard List Controller alternative for the future pipeline for Lightning Data Service. Untill they That's only available for VF pages